# XSLT - Add '<' & '>' to variable

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, mule

I use a variable in my `XSLT`style:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pref="URI_SOAP_WS">

<xsl:param name="request" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
            xmlns:pref="URI_SOAP_WS">
            <soap:Body>
            <xsl:value-of select="$request" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
            <xsl:value-of select="$request" />
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
```

And I call it with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$request" />
```

But it returns only the name, without `<` and `>`.

How can I add that to that value?

Comment: If you want to create an element you don't concatenate <> but use the `xsl:element` instruction.

Comment: @Pawel Instead of `xsl:value-of` ?

Comment: xsl:value-of gets the value of whatever is referenced.  Essentially, it returns plain text.  In your case, it returns what ever is contained in your $request variable.  It only returns text and not an element.  As @Pawel mentioned, if you want to create a dynamic element, you use xsl:element.  See [http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_element.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_element.asp) for how to use that and [http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_value_of.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_value_of.asp) for more on xsl:value-of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xsl:element` to wrap your data.

```
<xsl:element name="{$request}">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:element>
```